# What about eigenvectors of orthogonal matrices?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

I have known that the real eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices include 1 or -1, but how about the eigenvectors of orthogonal matrices? It seems that few resources discuss this issue. I am curious that whether eigenvectors of orthogonal matrices are similar to that of symmetric matrices, like they both have orthogonal eigenvectors with different eigenvalues. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}$ is orthogonal, and has eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Why do you think that orthogonal matrices have only $\pm 1$ as eigenvalues? And also, why is it that symmetric matrices always have orthogonal eigenvectors with different eigenvalues?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reminders. My expressions were imprecise. For orthogonal matrices, if they happen to have real eigenvalues, then the eigenvalues must be 1 or -1. For real symmetric matrices, if they have distinct eigenvalues, corresponding eigenvectors must be orthogonal. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes to both questions.